# How to open a binary file as raw string in python?

Tags: python, binaryfiles, rawstring

I have a macro written in imageJ script. I need to rewrite this macro to python3.4. I have opened a binary file in reading mode:

```
b_f = open("image.bin", "rb")
OverScan = 0
sizeY = 480
reg = OverScan + 10
```

Then I came into problems when trying to find a way how to open `b_f` as a raw string. In imageJ script it looks like that:
`s=File.openAsRawString(b_f,2*192*(1+sizeY)*reg);`
`File.openAsRawString(path, count)` - Opens a file and returns up to the first count bytes as a string.

Is there some easy way in python how to open a binary file as raw string?
I am totally new to python.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `b_f=open("image.bin", "rb").read()`?

Comment: Not yet, I will try thanks a lot, but how can I specify there that it should be read as raw string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have opened a file, that file reference has a `read()` method on it which takes the number of bytes that you want to read in.

```
with open("image.bin", "rb") as b_f:
    OverScan = 0
    sizeY = 480
    reg = OverScan + 10
    binary_data = b_f.read(2*192*(1+sizeY)*reg)
```

`binary_data` will now be of type `bytes` and hold the number of bytes that you have asked for

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to read the entire file into memory, simply calling the file's `read()` method (with no arguments) will do.

Eg:

```
s = open("image.bin", "rb").read()
```

If you only wish to read up to a specific number of bytes (as in @Eric Dill's example), that can be passed as a parameter to the `read` method:

```
s = open("image.bin", "rb").read(SOME_NUMBER_OF_BYTES)
```